# How to select pairs from two lists/?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have two lists from which I want to select pairs in such a way that each item in one set is paired with another item in the other set only when they are not the same. This is the code I tried so far.

```
start1 = [1, 4, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]
end1 = [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4]

for x in start1:
    for y in end1:
        if x != y:
            print(x,y)
```

The above code gives me results that look like this...

```
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 4
1 4
4 0
4 0
4 0
4 2
4 1
4 2
4 2
4 1
.
.
.
```

However, trying to get results like this...

```
1 0
4 0
0 1
3 2
3 2
3 4
3 1
1 4
```

As I am new to python, I am having difficulties with this problem. Can someone kindly guide me to achieve my goal?

Regards.

Comment: Could you describe your output? It looked at first like you wanted pairs of the unique items in start1, end1, when items are not equal, but I notice you list the pair (3, 2) twice in your desired output. Was that intentional?

Comment: Yes please, that was intentional. the result I wanted has been shown to be generated by zipping the sets. Thanks so much for your concern :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip the lists together, filtering the results.

```
start1 = [1, 4, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]
end1 = [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4]

for x, y in zip(start1, end1):
    if x != y:
        print(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[item for item in zip(start1, end1) if item[0] != item[1]]
>> [(1, 0), (4, 0), (0, 1), (3, 2), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 1), (1, 4)]
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, plus the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.